# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch on android

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cordova

i just finished developing my iOS Application with Cordova. So now i want to do the same on Android. Everything works fine but: You cant Overscroll the content. I have a fixed header/footer, then a Picture and then some navigation points.

On iOS you can Scroll the Content so that you can see the clients logo in the background. On Android this doesn't work, you can not overscroll the content to see the logo.

I read that -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and overflow: scroll doesn't work on Android. But those questions were from 2011. Is it still not possible to make the content overscrollable on Android?

Thank you!!

```
.ScrollableWrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /*to make it smooth as native*/
    background:url(../img/start/bg_wrapper.jpg)no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 320px 480px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}

 #header {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 2;
    max-height: 45px !important;
    height: 45px !important;
}

#foooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can have a look at [iScroll](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5&ei=MpuiU6j5F5KY0QX56oDoAw&usg=AFQjCNGTM-4fpSSTb_f94aMdXz2r5v7JHA&sig2=kFm0NctsUI6d5IhdCPG1oA).